# How to upgrade present iPhone/iPad applications to iOS6 and iPhone 5 compatible

Tags: ios5, ios6, iphone-5

I would like to know that is it really necessary at this stage to make our under development apps compatible with iOS6 and iPhone5. I am developing an iPhone application which is in final stage. With in 10 days I have to submit it to the app store. So, if it is necessary to make our present/under development apps compatible with iOS6 and iPhone5, what steps should be taken? And if it is not that necessary, then what other precautions should I take?

Comment: you have to wait for anther 24 hours. Apple NDA still applicable till tom.. So we can't discuss until tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Xcode 4.5 GM. For the new resolution to be enabled on iPhone 5 and new iPod, you need to provide a launch image at the appropriate size. You also have to make sure that you views are resolution independent and resize correctly. You can test on the simulator.

Since you'll be using the new Xcode, you might as well "modernize" your code to use the [new Objective C literals syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) for arrays, dictionaries and `NSNumber` objects. This will make your code much more readable (this is probably debatable, but that's my opinion).
These are compiler additions, and should work for any iOS target.

Other SDK additions, such as auto-layout support, will be probably irrelevant for you as you will want to target older iOS devices as well for now. But it is worth taking a look at the documentation to be familiar.

There are changes to the autorotation flows with views and windows. Again, check the documentation for the changes and how to prepare for iOS6.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about design patterns? What will be the new or modified things that we will have to follow?

Comment: Some additions you might not be able to use if you intend to target older iOS devices. I edited my answer to include some of these features.

Comment: Follow-up question: do you have a reference for 'You need to use Xcode 4.5 GM' and, if so, in what capacity must it be used? I've been trying to find a citable resource to say whether — for the short term at least — one can use 4.5 to develop and test but then build under 4.4 for submission. One might want to do that if they have a sizeable ARMv6 user base and don't want to give them the heave ho until they absolutely have to but would nevertheless like to support the iPhone 5. So I guess the question is: how will an iPhone 5 react if a -568h launch screen exists but there's no ARMv7s code.

Comment: That's a good question, to which I don't have an answer, but I'll try and do an educated guess. When we compiled against the 5.0 SDK with an older Xcode, our app ran on the new iPad, of course, but it would not display retina graphics, despite the 2x files being there. My guess is, same will happen here - a letterboxed version will show under iPhone 5. You could probably hack an older Xcode to target a newer SDK, but then you would probably have trouble with armv6 compatibility.

Comment: My advice - drop it. It is no longer need. The original iPhone is so old, the 3G is not supported with iOS 5. So you are two generations behind. The most you can do perhaps is branch off, so you can leave the old apps working, and create new versions for iOS 5 and up.

Comment: @LeoNatan Flurry reports 10% of my user base using ARMv6 devices, and this is an app that launched less than 6 months ago so those are people that have downloaded this year. So if I'm forced to pick then it makes more sense to ignore the iPhone 5 until I think that full-screen support on it would be likely to add at least 10% to my user base, and that's certainly not going to be for a while.

Comment: Actually that's incorrect. If you look at previous statistics, you'll see that iPhone adoption is very quick, as is new iOS. In fact, out of these 10 percent, it is likely a substantial size of that will probably move to iPhone 5. Meanwhile, you will offer subpar support for iPhone 5 users, which is unacceptable, in my book. Always look forward. What good will it do you you if iPhone 5 users test your app, find out it's not well supported and move to a competing software? You always want to be in the front, quickly supporting the new device, especially with Apple, where most people upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I would like to know about maps now. Will google maps remain functional in iOS6? Or this new iOS6 will only support Apple Maps?